# Cant update or install packages, dpkg error code (2)

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, dpkg

I had a power shortage and had to use fsck to restore some files to start my ubuntu 16.04 again.

Now when I want to install or update packages, I get an error and the process stops. It looks like the file list files may be corrupt.

Now, when I do `apt-get upgrade` I get the next error:

```
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 files list for package 'debianutils' is not a regular file
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

And a look at this file shows:

```
florian@PC15-085:/var/lib/dpkg/info$ ls debianutils.*
debianutils.md5sums  debianutils.postinst  debianutils.postrm

debianutils.list:
dependency_links.txt  entry_points.txt  PKG-INFO  top_level.txt
```

debianutils.list is not a txt file, but kind of a directory. I dont know if this is supposed to be like this. I tried to use `apt-get purge` and reinstall but then I get errors for packages with unmet dependencies.

How can I fix this?